# Post hoc test for robust mixed design ANOVA using R

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, post-hoc, robust

I have calculated a **robust** mixed ANOVA because I have no homogeneity of the error variances nor of the covariances (with a 2 level between-subject and a 2 level within-subject variable).
Can I calculate "**normal**" post hoc tests? Or are there special **robust** post hoc tests? (I do not want to calculate contrasts). What are the commands? Or does anyone have a manual?

Here is my code for the robust mixed ANOVA:
(dependent variable=Distanz, between-subject variable=Bed, within-subject variable=Standort)

```
WRS2::bwtrim(Distanz ~ Bed*Standort, id = ID, data = Dataset_ID)

mixedanova <- WRS2::bwtrim(Distanz ~ Bed*Standort, id = ID, data = Dataset_ID, tr = 0.2)
mixedanova

sppbb(Distanz ~ Bed*Standort, ID, data = Dataset_ID, est = "mom", nboot = 500) 
sppbi(Distanz ~ Bed*Standort, ID, data = Dataset_ID, est = "mom", nboot = 500) 
sppba(Distanz ~ Bed*Standort, ID, data = Dataset_ID, est = "mom", nboot = 500)
```

Comment: You would want to use robust post-hoc methods that match the method of the omnibus model.  Unfortunately, I find the functions in *WRS2* difficult to follow in this process. For example, it looks like your omnibus model uses trimmed means, while what you are using for post-hoc tests is using M-estimators. ...  How about using something like *MASS::rlm* for an omnibus model, which is then supported by the *emmeans* package for post-hoc analysis ?  (See: [cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html))

Answer (score 0):

I could not find this either in my exact case, but I would say that you do not need them in this 2x2 context. If you find differences, be them between, within or in interactions, you just have two levels per group so you would not need post hoc at all. A graph should be enough in this case to interpret the interaction effect.

Comment: Sorry, I have made a slip of the pen: I have **3 x 5 Design** 
(3 level between-subject x 5 level within-subject variable). 

Therefore, unfortunately, I do need post hoc tests...